# 面白イースターエッグ

Tags: untagged

例えば、

```
$ aptitude -vvvvv moo
```

のような、面白イースターエッグが知りたいのです。

Comment: この質問は適切かどうかを討議するため、[meta]に質問を投稿してください。

Comment: Metaに[質問](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1417/適切な質問かの討議-面白イースターエッグ)を投稿しました。メタで討議が必要と考えた理由は、質問の範囲が広すぎて適切な回答が難しいと考えたからです。
なお、メタで話していますが、信用度が5以上じゃないと投稿できないため‌​、コメントに書いて頂ければ、そこに追加します。

Comment: メタでの討議にこのような質問は適切ではないとの判断があったため、そしてコミュニティの中のクローズ投票がありましたので、とりあえずクローズをさせました。疑問点があれば、[メタで共有してください](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1417/%E9%81%A9%E5%88%87%E3%81%AA%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%8E%E8%AD%B0-%E9%9D%A2%E7%99%BD%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0#1421)

Answer (score 1):

`$ python -c "import this"`
でThe Zen of Pythonが表示されます．

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
from __future__ import braces
import antigravity
import __hello__
import this
```

cli:

```
apt-get moo
apt-get help
```

Firefox

```
about:robots
```

Answer (score 0):

- Vim
  `:help 42`
- Firefox
  `about:mozilla`
- apt-build
  `apt-build moo`